# Cantidad de select deben ser iguales - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Buen dia, tengo dos input y un boton que se llama generar select, al darle clic al boton se me genera dos select donde cada uno me carga la cantidad de números que haya colocado en los inputs, por ejemplo si en el input uno agrego 5 y en el input 2 agrego el valor de 7 al momento de darle al botón me genera un select con los numeros del 1 al 5 y otro select con los numeros del 1 al 7, y al seleccionar algun numero de los dos select se me genera otro select con el valor que sigue por ejemplo en el select1 seleccione el valor de 2 entonces el select que se genera del selct1 aparecen el resto de numeros del 3 al 5 y asi hasta llegar al cinco.

Lo que necesito es que el select2 cuando el sistema comienza a generar mas selects que no sea mayor a la cantidad de selects que tiene el select 1:
ejemplo como no debe quedar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como quiero que quede, donde el select2 no supere la cantidad de selects creados del select1:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'


let initialState = {
  first: null,
  arraySelect: []
};

 function Pruebas(props) {



  const [arraySelect, setarraySelect] = useState(initialState.arraySelect);
  const [numberIni, setnumberIni] = useState(initialState.first);

  const [arraySelect2, setarraySelect2] = useState(initialState.arraySelect);
  const [numberIni2, setnumberIni2] = useState(initialState.first);

  const getArray = (value) => {
    let arr = [];
    {
      let reco = Math.round(numberIni - parseInt(value));
      console.log(reco);

      if (parseInt(value) == numberIni) {
        return false;
      }
      Array(reco)
        .fill(1)
        .map((value2, key) => {
          arr.push(parseInt(value) + parseInt(key + 1));
        });
    }
    return arr;
  };


  const getArray2 = (value) => {
    let arr2 = [];
    {
      let reco2 = Math.round(numberIni2 - parseInt(value));
      console.log(reco2);

      if (parseInt(value) == numberIni2) {
        return false;
      }
      Array(reco2)
        .fill(1)
        .map((value2, key0) => {
          arr2.push(parseInt(value) + parseInt(key0 + 1));
        });
    }
    return arr2;
  };

  const setSelect = (value) => {
    let isArray = getArray(value);
    if (isArray) {
      setarraySelect([...arraySelect, isArray]);
    }
  };

  const setSelect2 = (value) => {
    let isArray = getArray2(value);
    if (isArray) {
      setarraySelect2([...arraySelect2, isArray]);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setnumberIni(event.target.numberIni.value);
    setnumberIni2(event.target.numberIni2.value);
  };
  const resetForm = () => {
    setnumberIni(null);
    setnumberIni2(null);
    setarraySelect([]);
    setarraySelect2([]);
  };

 
  return (
    <div>

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>


<input type="number" name="numberIni" placeholder="Select1" /> <br />
<input type="number" name="numberIni2" placeholder="Select2" /> <br />
       
        <button  type="submit"  className="btn btn-success" >Generar Select</button>
      </form>
      <div class="row">

      <div class="col-sm-2">

      {numberIni && (
        <div> <label><font size="2">Select1:&nbsp; </font></label>
          <select  onChange={(e) => setSelect(e.target.value)} name="" id="">
            <option value="seleccione">Seleccione</option>
            {Array(parseInt(numberIni))
              .fill(1)
              .map((value, key) => {
                return <option value={key + 1}>{key + 1}</option>;
              })}
          </select>

          {Array(parseInt(numberIni))
            .fill(1)
            .map((value, key2) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  {arraySelect[key2] && (
                    <>
                    <label><font size="2">select1&nbsp; </font> </label>
                      <select
                     
                        onChange={(e) => setSelect(e.target.value)}
                        name=""
                        id=""
                      >
                        <option value="seleccione">Seleccione</option>
                        {arraySelect[key2].map((value, key3) => {
                          return (
                            <option value={arraySelect[key2][key3]}>
                              {arraySelect[key2][key3]}
                            </option>
                          );
                        })}
                      </select>
                    </>
                  )}
                </div>
              );
            })}
        </div>



      )}


</div>

<div class="col-sm-2">



{numberIni2 && (
        <div>
           <label><font size="2">select2 &nbsp; </font> </label>
          <select  onChange={(e) => setSelect2(e.target.value)} name="" id="">
            <option value="seleccione">Seleccione</option>
            {Array(parseInt(numberIni2))
              .fill(1)
              .map((value, key0) => {
                return <option value={key0 + 1}>{key0 + 1}</option>;
              })}
          </select>
          <label><font size="2"></font> </label>

          {Array(parseInt(numberIni2))
            .fill(1)
            .map((value, key02) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  {arraySelect2[key02] && (
                    <>
                     <label><font size="2">select2</font> </label>
                      <select
                     
                        onChange={(e) => setSelect2(e.target.value)}
                        name=""
                        id=""
                      >
                        <option value="seleccione">Seleccione</option>
                        {arraySelect2[key02].map((value, key03) => {
                          return (
                            <option value={arraySelect2[key02][key03]}>
                              {arraySelect2[key02][key03]}
                            </option>
                          );
                        })}
                      </select>
                      
                    </>
                  )}
                </div>
              );
            })}
            
        </div>



      )}
</div>

</div>
      {numberIni && (
        <input onClick={() => resetForm()} type="button" value="Reiniciar" />
      )}

      

    </div>





  
  );


  
};


export default Pruebas
```

Comment: Quieres que si colocan un numero mayor en el segundo input los select que se renderizen sean igual al numero del input 1?

Comment: no, osea me refiero a la cantidad de selects que aparezcan mas no al contenido de los selects, el select2 no debe superar la cantidad de select que hayan en el select1 , asi como explico en la imagen.

Comment: me puedes colabroar?